# string and character concatenation in C

Tags: c, string, string-concatenation

I was trying to implement LCS in C language, but am stuck at equivalent of following code in C :

```
return backtrack(C, X, Y, i-1, j-1) + X[i]
```

I tried using `strcat()` :

```
 char *str = sequence(arr,pGene1,pGene2,i-1,j-1);
 char chr= pGene1[i-1];
 char *chr1 = &chr;
 return strcat(str,chr1);
```

but it gives me a segmentation fault. In the above code `sequence` is a recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this function and now it works

```
    char * addchartostring(char * str, char mych){
          int l = strlen(str); 
          char *added = (char*)malloc((l+2)*sizeof(char)); 
          char ch[] = {mych, '\0'}; 
          strcpy(added, str);
          strcat(added, ch);
          return added; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `\0` terminator from `chr`. Also you don't really need the additional pointer `chr1`. The following should work:

```
 char *str = sequence(arr, pGene1, pGene2, i-1, j-1);
 char chr[2] = { pGene1[i-1], '\0' };
 return strcat(str, chr);
```

Comment: Make sure your `sequence` function allocates enough storage for additional characters to be appended. If not then you will need to create a new string for the result.

Comment: Yes that's what I was thinking. Thanks.